# Query for Dynamic Fields in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query some data in MongoDb that has a known document structure but the fields are not known. Here is three documents from my test collection. In this example, the fields "Data1" and "Data2" are known values but the fields within the sub-documents are not known (Ex. NumberOfVehicles, LocationOfIncident, & TestReason).

```
{
  "_id" : "5a32cf74cbf20b446c70f969",
  "CreatedDate" : "2017-12-14 19:22:05.233Z",
  "Data" : {
      "Data1" : [ 
          {
              "NumberOfVehicles" : "4",
              "LocationOfIncident" : "Hollywood"
          }
      ]
  }
},
{
  "_id" : "5a3abff0ccf20b17642214b7",
  "CreatedDate" : "2017-12-20T19:53:56.318Z",
  "Data" : {
      "Data1" : [ 
          {
              "NumberOfVehicles" : "5"
          }
      ]
  }
},
{
  "_id" : "5a0de88bccf20b2e649a89f4",
  "CreatedDate" : "2017-11-16T19:34:09.341Z",
  "Data" : {
      "Data2" : [ 
          {
              "TestReason" : "Random"
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

I would like to query a particular data section ("Data1") across all documents and get a result like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "5a32cf74cbf20b446c70f969",
  "CreatedDate" : "2017-12-14 19:22:05.233Z",
  "NumberOfVehicles" : "4",
  "LocationOfIncident" : "Bangor"
},
{
  "_id" : "5a3abff0ccf20b17642214b7",
  "CreatedDate" : "2017-12-20T19:53:56.318Z",
  "NumberOfVehicles" : "5"
}
```

I'm close, but just can't seem to get rid of the arrays. Here's what I have so far:

```
db.runCommand({
  aggregate: "test",
  pipeline: [
    { $group: { _id: "$Data.Data1" } },
    { $unwind: "$_id" }
  ]
}).result
```

which gives:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : {
            "NumberOfVehicles" : "4",
            "LocationOfIncident" : "Bangor"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "NumberOfVehicles" : "5"
        }
    }
]
```

Any suggestions on how to get it more into a tabular format like my desired format above? This data is being used in a third party reporting product and requires a more table-like structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with filtering your collection to leave only documents having `Data.Data1`. Then you need to unwind it to transform an array of elements into multiple documents with single item `Data1`. Then you have to move your two fields `_id` and `CreatedDate` two levels deeper into `Data1` to be able to use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to get exactly shape you need.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
  $match: {
    "Data.Data1": { $exists : true }
  } 
},
{ $unwind: "$Data.Data1" },
{
  $addFields: {
    "Data.Data1.CreatedDate": "$CreatedDate",
    "Data.Data1._id": "$_id"
  }
},
{
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: "$Data.Data1"
  }
}
])
```

Comment: Looks like `$addFields` and `$replaceRoot` are supported in a later version (v3.4) than I'm using (v3.2). I'll upgrade locally and try your solution.

Comment: If I'm unable to upgrade our environments (at least in the near future), can the same be accomplished in v3.2 with alternate methods?

Comment: Well you can still use $match and $unwind in 3.2 and then transform the data on the client side. It shouldn't affect the performance.

Comment: I upgraded locally to v3.4 and your query worked! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use below aggregation query in 3.6 version.

`$match` stage to filter documents where `Data1` is present.

`$unwind` to flatten the data in Data1.

`$mergeObjects` to merge the other document fields with `$let` expression to get rid of embedded document structure and project embedded Data1 fields.

`$replaceRoot` to promote the data to the top level.

`$project` with exclusion to drop the `Data` field.

```
db.testcol.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"Data.Data1":{$exists:true}}},
  {"$unwind":"$Data.Data1"},
  {"$replaceRoot":{
   "newRoot":{
    "$mergeObjects":[
      "$$ROOT", 
      {
        "$let":{
        "vars":{"data1":"$Data.Data1"},
        "in":"$$data1"
       }
      }
    ]
   }
 }},
 {"$project":{"Data":0}},
])
```

Comment: CreatedDate and _id will be lost in your solution.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't notice that part of question. Updated now.